# Nancy RequiresClaims failure returns a 403. How do I use this?

Tags: nancy

If a module requires a claim, and the user does not have the claim a 403 response is returned.
eg:

```
this.RequiresClaims(new[] { "SuperSecure" });
```

or

```
this.RequiresValidatedClaims(c => c.Contains("SuperSecure"));
```

but that just returns a blank page to the user.

How do I deal with a user not having the required claim? 
Can I 'catch' the 403 and redirect?

The RequiresClaims method returns void or uses the pre-request hook to throw back a HttpStatusCode.Forbidden. What should I do so the user knows what has happened?

Many Thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch it either by writing your own post request hook (either at the app level, or the module level) or by implementing your own [IErrorHandler](https://github.com/grumpydev/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/ErrorHandling/IErrorHandler.cs), probably wrapping the [default one](https://github.com/grumpydev/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/ErrorHandling/DefaultErrorHandler.cs).

The error handler stuff is going to change so you will be able to register multiple ones (for different error codes), it's setup to do that (with the "can/do" interface) but for some reason my brain didn't add it as a collection :-)

Comment: If anyone comes here from the future like me, be aware that IErrorHandler has been renamed to [IStatusCodeHandler](https://github.com/grumpydev/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/IStatusCodeHandler.cs). And the new default one is [DefaultStatusCodeHandler](https://github.com/grumpydev/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/ErrorHandling/DefaultStatusCodeHandler.cs)